# Как получить все ключи с одинаковыми значениями?

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, dict

Есть такой словарь : `mydict = {'main':'open','second':'close','third':'open'}`. Надо из него получить все ключи со значениями `'open'`.

Пробовал такой код:

```
mydict = {'main':'open','second':'close','third':'open'}
print(list(mydict.keys())[list(mydict.values()).index('open')])
```

Он выводит только `main`. Как вывести все ключи со значением `'open'`?

Comment: Привет, , я рекомендую принять ответ от CrazyElf or @dIm0n т.к. карентли принятый -- немного костыль, а мой просто вариация на тему ;)

Comment: Привет Да легко) Просто я отметил самый первый и всё, потом пошёл кодить

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Изучите *списковые включения*, они очень часто пригождаются в питоне, поскольку позволяют довольно кратко и понятно делать выборки:

```
mydict = {'main':'open','second':'close','third':'open'}
print([k for k in mydict if mydict[k] == "open"])
```

Вывод:

```
['main', 'third']
```

По сути, это тоже самое решение из другого ответа, только записанное в одну строку и без использования переменной для накопления списка.

Answer (score 5):

Можно так сделать:

```
mydict = {'main':'open','second':'close','third':'open'}
mylist = []

for i in mydict:
    if mydict[i] == 'open':
        mylist.append(i)
```

Answer (score 5):

Вариация:

```
print(*filter('open'.__eq__, mydict.values()))
```

Comment: У меня ничего не выводит почему-то )  А так то было бы красиво. `mydict` всё-таки итерируется же по ключам, а не по значениям

Comment: @CrazyElf edited, thx

Comment: `AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'count'`

Comment: @CrazyElf То убрал, правы, спс. Вообще мое решение не совсем то, что надо, это как бы вариация ;)

Answer (score 2):

Вот так вот:

```
mydict = {'main': 'open', 'second': 'close', 'third': 'open'}
print(list(filter(lambda k: mydict[k] == 'open', mydict)))
```

Comment: Во, вот такой я хотел сделать, а получилась чушь  ;) +1